# How to join first n lines in a file

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I am trying to clean up some data, and I would eventually like to put it in CSV form.

I have used some regular expressions to clean it up, but I'm stuck on one step.

I would like to replace all but every third newline (\n) with a comma.

The data looks like this:

```
field1
field2
field3
field1
field2
field3
```

etc..

I need it in

```
field1,field2,field3
field1,field2,field3
```

Anyone have a simple way to do this using sed or awk? I could write a program and use a loop with a mod counter to erase every 1st and 2nd newline char, but I'd rather do it from the command line if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{n2=n1;n1=n;n=$0;if(NR%3==0){printf"%s,%s,%s\n",n2,n1,n}}' yourData.txt
```

This script saves the last three lines and print them at every third line. Unfortunately, this works only with files having a multiple of 3 lines.

A more general script is:

```
awk '{l=l$0;if(NR%3==0){print l;l=""}else{l=l","}}END{if(l!=""){print substr(l,1,length(l)-1)}}' yourData.txt
```

In this case, the last three lines are concatenated in a single string, with the comma separator inserted whenever the line number is not a multiple of 3. At the end of the file, the string is printed if it is not empty with the trailing comma removed.

Answer (score 5):

Awk version:

```
awk '{if (NR%3==0){print $0;}else{printf "%s,", $0;}}'
```

Answer (score 4):

A Perl solution that's a little shorter and that handles files that don't have a multiple of 3 lines:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/,/ if(++$i%3&&! eof)' yourData.txt
```

Comment: Good one on the non-mulitple-of-three files.  I knew mine didn't handle it but didn't see the solution in 3 minutes I took on this.

Answer (score 1):

cat file | perl -ne 'chomp(); print $_, !(++$i%3) ? "\n" : ",";'

Answer (score 1):

Use *nawk* or */usr/xpg4/bin/awk* on *Solaris*:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?OFS:RS' OFS=, infile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
paste -sd',,\n' file
```

or this:

```
sed '$!N;$!N;y/\n/,/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

vim version:

```
:1,$s/\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/,\1,\2\r/g
```

Answer (score 0):

awk '{ORS=NR%3?",":"\n";print}' urdata.txt